# Laravel 5 refresh login page after session times out

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5

I have seen many posts very similar question and they talk about redirecting to login page when of course you are logged in and a session times out.

My problem is the Login page itself which is using `auth:guest` middle-ware.

If I am on Login page... for 120mins and session times out and now I enter credentials and click submit button I get `TokenMismatchException` error.

I want to refresh login page when session has expired such that it has a new csrf token.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following to the app/Exception/Handler

```
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
```

and to render method

```
if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
     if ( !$request->ajax() ) {
         return redirect()->back()->withInput();
     }
}
```